# Form action, form created with mailchimp in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, mailchimp

I have installed the mailchimp plugin for wordpress on my site.
I have created a form in the admin panel. It sends emails to subscribers. It created a link like: https:\link\form-id\subscribe.
Now I need to add something like this in the form, when someone subscribes to my form, i need this to execute as well:

```
        $url_subscribe_service = "my-link";
        $client_subscribe_service = curl_init($url_subscribe_service);
        curl_setopt($client_subscribe_service,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
        $response_subscribe_service = curl_exec($client_subscribe_service);
```

But I don't know where to add that on the server, which file ?
I thought somewhere inside forms folder from includes, like class-form-listener.php, but it doesn't do nothing, not even die() doesn't execute, so that must be the wrong file.
What file executes the generated url/form ?

Can you help me with that, please ?
Please excuse my English errors, I am not an English native.

Comment: I searched for "*wordpress mailchimp plugin*" which took me to [MC4WP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mailchimp-for-wp/). The description on that page includes a "customizing" section which says "*The plugin provides various filter & action hooks that allow you to modify or extend default behavior*", and links to a [collection of examples](https://github.com/ibericode/mc4wp-snippets).  There's an example there called [modify-data-before-sending-to-mailchimp](https://github.com/ibericode/mc4wp-snippets/blob/master/modify-data-before-sending-to-mailchimp.php) ...

Comment: ... which seems to show a hook which runs code before subscribing someone, and examples of how to call it.  Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found out that mailchimp sends source code for forms on their server, so I can't really access it. For the thing that I needed, I don't have many options. The best options, I think, is to change my mailchimp form with a classic landingpage. Thank you!